# CSAPP problem 2.6, show int and show float question

Tags: c

```
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void show_int(int x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_float(float x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
}
int main() {
    int a = 3510593;
    int b = 3510593.0;
    show_int(b);  // line 1
    show_int(a);  // line 2
    show_float(b); // line 3
}
```

show_int a and b show the same output: 41 91 35 00, while show_float b is 04 45 56 4a?
Given the show byte implementation, why line 1 and line 2 show the same result?

Comment: Why do you expect not to be shown the same result for the same value of the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` is an `int` even though you've declared it with a `float` literal.  Therefore, its value is just 3510593 and hence `a` and `b` are identical chunks of memory.

When you pass `b` into `show_float`, it's converted into its `float` equivalent and hence has a different byte representation.

Comment: thanks, I see, I made a mistake in the type of b.